# Looking for a more declarative Rx way to observe when the item properties change

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a collection which is observable from an Rx point of view, the items are also observable (from an Rx point of view).

I want to be able to observe when the properties of the items in the collection change, but the collection size can be modified - add, removes etc. When this happens I want to re-subscribe to the properties of the items in the collection.

I have code that works, but I'm looking for something more elegant\declarative without having to use a Subject<T>.

```
    private _favourites = new ObservableCollection<Favourite>();
    ...

    public IObservable<Unit> FavouritesChanged()
    {
        var disposable = new SerialDisposable();
        var subject = new Subject<Unit>();

        _favourites.ObserveCollectionChanged()
            .Subscribe(x =>
                       {
                           disposable.Disposable = _favourites.Select(y => y.ObservePropertyChanged())
                               .Merge()
                               .Select(y => Unit.Default)
                               .Subscribe(subject);
                       });

        return subject;
    }       
}
```

Comment: What is `_favourites`?

Comment: And what is `AsUnit()`?

Comment: I'm assuming you're working off of https://www.codeproject.com/articles/885009/attached-vm-behaviours?

Comment: @Shlomo - nope never seen it before

Comment: @Enigmativity - changed code, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `.Switch()` is what you need. `.Switch()` takes an `IObservable<IObservable<T>>` and returns an `IObservable<T>` that produces values from only the latest inner `IObservable<T>`. It handles all of the unsubscribes from the previous values of the outer observable.

Try this:

```
public IObservable<Unit> FavouritesChanged()
{
    return
        _favourites
            .ObserveCollectionChanged()
            .Select(c =>
                _favourites
                    .Select(y => y.ObservePropertyChanged())
                    .Merge()
                    .AsUnit())
            .Switch();
}
```

Comment: lol - you're so right, I'd just forgotten from last time I needed to Switch()

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple problems with the code you posted. I don't know whether you want to replicate the problems or not:

1. Items removed from the collection aren't removed from the observable stream.
2. The observable stream is just `Unit` values, which offers no clue as to which child object, or which property of which child object, got altered. That leaves you with refreshing everything, which seems rather inefficient.

@Enigmativity's answer fixes item 1, and is the probably the most correct answer given the information posted. Item 2 is a design flaw, which you may want to fix.

Comment: Neither of these are problems with the code, 1 - is taken care of by the subscription being persisted in the SerialDisposable, even when an item is deleted from the collection the subscription is re-created. 2 - you are assuming I care which item in the collection changed, in this case I don't, I justed wanted to know when a specific behaviour had happened on any of the members.